# C# Razor Redirect to route after post without affecting history

Tags: c#, razor, razor-pages

As the title suggests, I am trying to redirect to a route from a Razor Page without altering the browser's history state.

After saving some data to a database, let's say to the url ../User/1, I am performing a redirect to a route like so:

```
return RedirectToRoute(null, new { id = identifier });
```

As I understand it, this is important as to follow the RESTful pattern. It also accounts for the fact that if the URL was ../User/0 for a new user, the redirect will now take you to the URI of the created user, say ../User/2.

This works great, my problem however, is that the redirect appends to the browsers history (obviously), so if I save an existing user and click the Back button in the browser, I'm just taken to the exact same page.

Is there a way I can, after making that POST, have a way of refreshing or reloading the current page, optionally with different route data, so that when the user goes back in their browser, they are taken to the previous logical page?.

I know this sort of behaviour is achievable in Javascript, but is there some way I can handle it directly in the post request in my backend code?

I've tried the different forms of redirect, for instance:

```
return RedirectToAction(null, new { id = identifier });
```

and:

```
return RedirectToRoute(null, new { id = identifier });
```

As well as just:

```
return Page();
```

But this one doesn't let me change any route data, nor keeps properties bound to the page.

Comment: It is not possible to achieve this kind of behavior purely on the backend. It's because once a response is sent from the server to the client, the server has no control over the client's behavior and browser is your client. So the browser is the one that manages the history state.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. When returning a redirect like this, is it possible client-side via Javascript to ignore the instruction to redirect, but instead look at the url that was passed and reload with it? @VadimMartynov

Comment: Of course. There are 2 ways to implement with the help of the client. 1. Use SPA principles, call request from js and interpret and navigate user manually. 2. Manually manipulate browser history after redirect with JS to change it. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState for details.